# Connector for sliding plate to rotating rod

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, connections

I want to couple a plate, which cannot rotate but only slide along a track, with a threaded rotating shaft. This is for a grip setup, where rotating the rod presses the plate forwards to apply pressure.

I don't know of a type of connector for this coupling, and have searched the internet but McMaster and other sites do not seem to have one. Does anyone else know of such a connection?

Answer (score 1):

Use a nut or threaded boss fixed or welded to the plate.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a "Flanged Nut"

These are typically manufactured for trapezoidal lead-screw type threads, but are also available in the more standard metric/imperial threadforms.

There are of course all sorts of variants of these, but without more information regarding your application, there's not much I can do to provided a more targeted recommendation.

[image: flanged nut]